# Одинаковый margin на разных экранах

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте!

Есть такой layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_prefpadding"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_prefpadding"/>
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы margin у TextView слева и у EditText справа был одинаковый на разных экранах. Пробовал создавать директории values с разными суффиксами: -small, -normal, -large, -xlarge (values-small и тд) и файлом dimens.xml в них с разными значениями. Вот пример записи:

```
<dimen name="dim_prefpadding">10dip</dimen>
```

Это отчасти помогло на некоторых устройствах, но на остальных все равно: по отношению к другим компонентам отступ где-то больше, где-то меньше.
Как сделать чтобы он был одинаков везде? Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

-small, -normal, -large, -xlarge  - устаревшие. Сейчас используется:

ldpi - малая плотность, около 120dpi;

mdpi - средняя плотность, около 160dpi;

hdpi - повышенная плонтность, около 240dpi;

xhdpi - сверх повышенная плотность, около 320dpi;

nodpi - используется для изображений, которые не должны масштабироваться в зависимости от плотности экрана

Comment: спасибо за ответ, подожду еще немного, вдруг кто-то ответит

Comment: Правильнее было бы сказать, что атрибуты small, -normal, -large, -xlarge определяют размер дисплея, а ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi - разрешение дисплея - https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

Comment: в ответе как минимум 3 момента в корне неверных. 
1.-small, -normal, -large, -xlarge - устаревшие
2.около 120dpi; ???
3.nodpi - используется для изображений

Ответы:
1.Не устаревшие
2.Не около, а абсолютно равные этому значению.
3.Далеко не только для изображений. И это ресурсы для всех плотностей

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, так как быть тогда?